# SASS - &:last-child, &.last-child not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, sass, css-selectors

I've got SASS code like this:

```
li {
  &:last-child, &.last-child {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

And HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="last-child">Hello there!</li>
</ul>
```

Code above it's not working in IE8. I know that IE8 it's not supporting :last-child, I defined .last-child for this purpose.

When I edit SASS code to this:

```
li {
  &:last-child {
    color: red;
  }

  &.last-child {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Everything is working now, but it leads to code duplication.

I'm adding .last-child for IE8 with with JS function, but I think it doesn't matter.

**Example**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LFGAr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you simply can't combine an unsupported selector with a supported selector. The browser *has* to drop the entire rule. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets).

Since you're adding the `.last-child` class with JS, it may be easiest to just make use of that class and forgo the use of `:last-child` for the simple reason that it's not supported in IE8. If you want to use `:last-child` and remove IE8 support later if it ever becomes an option, then you'll have to live with the code duplication for the time being.